# What are the graphs representing relations over finite sequences?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

A directed graph can be said to represent a relation between elements.
For instance, the following defines a relation $\sim$
such that $A\sim B$, $B\sim A$ and $A\sim C$.

[image: A directed graph with edges connecting A-B, B-A, and A-C]

A directed hypergraph then represents a relation between sets of elements.
The example here defines a $\sim$ where $\{A,B\}\sim\{C\}$.

[image: A directed hypergraph with a single related pair: {A,B}-{C}]

Recently I have come to need a representation for relations not between elements,
not between sets of elements,
but between finite sequences of elements.
The following describes a $\sim$
with a single related pair: $\langle A,B\rangle\sim\langle C\rangle$.
The labels on the graph-edges here indicate position(s) in the sequences.

[image: A sequence-relation with a single related pair AB-C]

Both the set-relation and this sequence-relation are represented as bipartite digraphs.
The only difference is that the latter is edge-labeled, with some restrictions on the labeling.
I'm certainly not the first to deal with such relations,
and the translation between relations and graphlike things is natural,
so I'm wondering:
What are these sequence-relating graphs called,
and where might one read more about them?